# UIlabel inside tableViewCell alignment depending on size class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, storyboard

I have TableViewController with prototype cell for AnyxAny:
[image: anyxany]

And I made some small changes for CompactxAny
[image: compactxany]

I would like to have Description label alignment of text be set to left on CompactxAny. Is there storyboard/Swift code hack? I can deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

We need to **install and uninstall** some constraints. I have two constraints on label **Description** in wAny hAny

1. Top space
2. Trailing space

Uninstall these two constraints in wCompact hAny

Apply the following constraints:

1. Leading space of description label and Temperature label
2. Vertical space between description label and temperature label

Have a look at this:

[image]

Comment: Its working fine with, I can see it, I think It might be an issue with browser, Check it with different browser